# What happens if I don't remove database created using QSqlDatabase?

Tags: database, qt, qsqlquery, qtsql, qsqldatabase

The manual describes the correct way to remove database is :

```
{
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase (...);
QSqlQuery query (db);
query.exec (...); 
}

QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase (...);
```

What happens if I close the database but not remove it explicitly?

Comment: I guess, if you simply close a database connection without removing it, you can open it again. If you also remove it, you must add it again and then open.

Comment: From the memory perspective, does closing and not removing have concerns around memory leaks?